# Camera direct to OpenGL texture on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, opengl-es-2.0, ios-camera

On Android, it is possible to make the camera write its output directly to an OpenGL texture (of type GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES), avoiding buffers on the CPU altogether.

Is such a thing possible on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you get from the camera in iOS is a `CMSampleBufferRef`, with a `CVPixelBufferRef` inside. (See documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/Reference/reference.html)). iOS from version 5 has `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` in the CoreVideo framework, which allows you to create an OpenGL ES texture using a `CVPixelBufferRef`, avoiding any copies.

Check the [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) sample in Apple's developer website, it's all there.